# Following other object with delay in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity, and attempting to have one character move after another in order to attack them. In order to make this movement look natural, I want to add a delay, i.e. character follows the exact path other character took, but 0.5 seconds behind.

Since I'm utilizing the State Pattern for my characters behaviour, the movement logic is in a scriptable object. This means I don't directly have access to Update() or IEnumerator, but I work around this by passing in a reference to a MonoBehaviour script attached to the characterGameObject (not sure if this part is relevant, but included just in case there was some weird side effect that I didn't know about).

I first tried to use IEnumerator, with every Execute() call of the scriptable object (which occurs once every game tick) starting a couroutine which first waited for a set amount of time, and then moved the object.

```
void Execute(StateController stateController){

Vector3 movementVector = 
Vector3.MoveTowards(actor.transform.position,targetWithOffset,
Time.deltaTime);

stateController.StartCoroutine(stateController.MoveTorwards(movementVector, 
    delay));

}

public IEnumerator MoveTorwards(Vector3 movementVector, float delay)
{
yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
gameObject.transform.position = movementVector;
}
```

However, this resulted in an extremely weird glitchy movement, where the character constantly teleported around itself as it moved torwards the target.

Does anyone have insight into this? Am I missing a fundamentally simple implementation, or was my method correct and the glitchy movement has come from a side effect (doubtful, because the code works perfectly without the IEnumerator, and the glitch still occurs when the delay var is set to zero.

Comment: You need to do this with a List or Queue and a structure of position, rotation and time between each movements. You can then use this on your other object. Once each structure is used, remove it. If you attempt to do what I just said above but run into issue then edit your question with that code.

Comment: @Programmer Recording time isn't needed; giving a `speed` to the "follower" takes less data and is more flexible. Also, assuming the "follower" always looks "forward" in the path, rotation isn't needed either, as it can be figured out from the direction from current position or last node, to the position of the next node.

Comment: The post above is a technique I used to implement record and playback function and it worked great than not recording the rotation and time. I always moved the rotation of the other object and don't know if OP needs to  rotate that too but I assume that to save making further comments.  Also, subtract the speed from the recorded time. You simply get more accurate result with that especially if the delay time is long(1 second and above).

Comment: @AlmightyR  *"giving a speed to the "follower" takes less data and is more flexible"*...Yeah but then if you need to delay the other object with a long time like 1 second or more, it won't work well. The other object will be skipping position/rotation. It would look like cutting a line and not what you would expect. *This could actually cause the following object to go through other objects which is not a good idea* unless OP is fine with this.

Comment: *"The other object will be skipping position/rotation."* - How? I'm not talking about making the "follower" assume the recorded position of the "followed" every frame (with a delay); A better algorithm would be to make the "follower" actually *follow* the path as a *path*, rather than as a set of points. A point-to-point algorithm wouldn't allow *"skipping"* behavior like that. --- Also, AFAIK, without further checks, either algorithm could make the *"ghost-through"* effect that you describe; and in fact it's even *worse* in case of setting (no physics) instead of following (can do w physics).

Answer (score 0):

> character follows the exact path other character took, but 0.5 seconds
>   behind.

---

### Step 1: Define what the *"exact path"* is.

Implement a *"consumable"* point-to-point `path` structure (ie `Queue<Vector3>`), and keep recording the path of the first character to it by recording it's current position on an update loop (ie `Update()`, directly or indirectly).

---

### Step 2: Try to *"consume"* the path from oldest node to newest.

For now, ignore the idea of a delay; just make sure that the path system to work, and that the movement looks right.

On each update (`Update()` or indirect) of the follower entity, move towards the next node in the path until it's reached; when it is, *"consume"* that node (remove from "path", ie `.Dequeue()`), and any next nodes that are so close as to be considered "reached"; this, obviously, will make the entity start walking towards next node, if there is any "unreached" node left.

---

### Step 3: Delay the following of the path at start and after the path is empty (and/or based on events & triggers if you need more than that).

When the path goes from a length/count of `<=1` nodes to `>1` nodes, before you start following the first (or next) segment, do the delay; this will create the effect you're looking for.

If the path's length ever gets `<=1` again, it means it's being consumed immediately upon creation, which means the "follower" entity has reached the "followed" entity. In this case, from your description, the "follower" entity ***attacks*** the "followed" entity; meaning the game is not instantly ended; in that case, to allow the "followed" to distance itself again (as is implied should be the case) after it starts moving, the delay is applied again before the "follower" starts following. --- This approach to the implementation of delay makes the behavior happen automagically to this case, as it's the same check as is done at "start" (actually a loop); no need for secondary checks.